# What should be the cause of this errors in build pipeline (.NET Core) in Azure devops

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have following YAML for the pipeline to build and publish the .NET azure function application artifacts:

```yaml
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'

test
archive artifacts
publish
```

Error:

[image]

I don't know what to do for this issue in the pipeline.
Could anyone help me..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `.net sdk` is not installed properly and the version of your build pipeline's .net version is not the same as your Function Trigger code.

[image]

I created one Azure Function App with .NET 6.0 version.

I have used the below YAML pipeline script to deploy my Function app like below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- master

variables:
  
  azureSubscription: 'subscription-id'

  
  functionAppName: 'valleyfunc74'

  
  vmImageName: 'windows-2019'

  
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/HTTPdotnetazfunc'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '6.x'  
        installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet  

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        projects: |
          $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
        arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration Release
        

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionApp
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]